# How to share developer account at LinkedIn

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have a developer account at LinkedIn. My question is if it's possible to connect other developers to it? We are three developers in our company that is working on the same app but on different platforms. I want them to have full access of the app info site, but I rather not give away my LinkedIn-password.
How do we arrange this in the best way? Anybody knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, I hope you're looking for following.

Goto https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps and select the app you want to make them administrator. Then select 'Roles' from the left menu and set them as administrator.